# why the model is doing prediction for first 5 days of the given month only

Tags: python, machine-learning

I attempted to do a prediction with an ARIMA model (with python).
P, D, Q, p,d,q values determined through ADF test, plot_acf, plot_pacf and can be shared if required.

Code is mentioned below.

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import statsmodels.api as sm


df = pd.read_csv(r'https://github.com/sreerajva5/ML/raw/master/sample_data_ts.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(df['sample_data'], order=(0,1,0), seasonal_order=(1,1,12,30))
result = model.fit()


future_dt = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2012-06-01', periods=60, freq='D'))
future_dt_df = pd.DataFrame(index=future_dt, columns=df.columns)
future_df = pd.concat([df, future_dt_df])
future_df['forecast'] = result.predict()
```

I created the model and attempted to predict next 60 days (2 months) numbers. But first five days of first month and first 5 days of second month values are getting predicted. In between values are not getting predicted.

Result received is given below.

```
"
2012-06-01  453.815056
2012-06-02  298.5604767
2012-06-03  270.5269854
2012-06-04  203.402702
2012-06-05  123.2703868

No values from predicted (its blank) against dates from 2012-06-06 to 2012-06-30
    
2012-07-01  475.5137062
2012-07-02  257.9273124
2012-07-03  272.8564157
2012-07-04  218.3305799
2012-07-05  123.9411595


Again no values from predicted (its blank) against dates from 2012-07-06 to 2012-07-30
"
```

What is the reason for this, and how can I get a proper prediction?

Comment: Executing your code gives me `ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.` Did you disable the warnings? Apparently you need to define that one index equals one period.

Comment: I also get the following warning, `ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it is not monotonic and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.`

Comment: could you provide subresults of the single steps? its hard to follow your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fit:**  The fit method estimates the parameters using the train/given data such that the error is minimum.

**predict:** Once the model parameters are estimated, the method can be used to make predictions on the train data as well can be used to make forecasts on the unseen data. Using the predict with no start and end data parameters will make predictions on the train data. Lets test it

```
assert len(result.predict()) == len(df)
ax = df.plot(figsize=(15,5))
result.predict().plot(ax=ax, label="predicted")
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

You can do predictions on out-of-sample/unseen data by specifying the start and end index. We will do predictions on full dateset by using `(0,len(future_df)-1)` as start and end index.

```
future_dt = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2012-06-01', periods=60, freq='D'))
future_dt_df = pd.DataFrame(index=future_dt, columns=df.columns)
future_df = pd.concat([df, future_dt_df])
future_df['forecast'] = result.predict(0,len(future_df)-1).values

# Lets plot it
ax = future_df['sample_data'][len(df)-10:].plot(figsize=(15,5))
future_df['forecast'][len(df)-10:].plot(ax=ax, label="predicted")
plt.legend()
```

[image]

**forecast:** This method is just a cut-down version of predict method which can be used to make predcitions of out-of-sample/unseen/future data without the need of start and end values. Lets do the forecast for next 60 days

```
future_dt = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2012-06-01', periods=60, freq='D'))
future_dt = pd.DataFrame(index=future_dt)
future_dt['forecast'] = result.forecast(60).values

ax = future_df['sample_data'][len(df)-10:].plot(figsize=(15,5))
future_dt['forecast'].plot(figsize=(15,5))
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Solution first:

Simply changing your last line from

```
future_df['forecast'] = result.predict()
```

to

```
future_df['forecast'] = result.forecast(60)
```

would do the magic.

## What you've done wrong (my guess)

The `predict()` method takes `start` and `end` 2 args. You've called the function without letting it know where to start predicting and when to stop, so it didn't work.

However, you did get the predictions for the first 5 days of both June and July, I guess there are some default values. I tried to look it up in the doc, it wasn't there.

Having this knowledge about `predict()` method, if you still want to use it instead of `forecast()`, what you can do is:

```
future_df['forecast'] = result.predict(start='2012-06-01', end='2012-07-30')
```

which should also work.